# MySQL trigger doesn't identify NEW.entity in subsequent queries?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger set up on the table 'purchase_invoice' which is supposed to add a corresponding stock transaction for the invoice item in the 'purchase_stock' table and update its stock units in the 'stock' table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addStock AFTER INSERT ON purchase_invoice
FOR EACH ROW

    INSERT INTO 
    purchase_stock
    (
       purchase_invoice_id,
       item_id,
       units,
       ...
    )
    VALUES
    (
       NEW.id,
       NEW.item_id,
       NEW.units
       ...
    );

    UPDATE 
       stock 
    SET 
       units = units + NEW.units 
    WHERE 
       item_id = NEW.item_id;
...
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Unknown column 'NEW.units'   in field list
Unknown column 'NEW.item_id' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `BEGIN` after `FOR EACH ROW`, therefore mysql interprets that the trigger is defined with a single insert statement only and considers the update statement separately. This is why you get the error message. Obviously, you are missing the corresponding `END` as well.

The correct code would look something like this:

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE TRIGGER addStock AFTER INSERT ON purchase_invoice
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
    purchase_stock
    (
       purchase_invoice_id,
       item_id,
       units,
       ...
    )
    VALUES
    (
       NEW.id,
       NEW.item_id,
       NEW.units
       ...
    );
    UPDATE 
       stock 
    SET 
       units = units + NEW.units 
    WHERE 
       item_id = NEW.item_id;
    ...
END\\

DELIMITER ;
```